# Showing that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cos x$ using complex exponentials

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Show that $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cos x$ using complex exponentials.

This is where I've got to:

$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)=\frac{i}{2}\left(e^{xi-\frac{\pi i}{2}}-e^{\frac{π}{2}-xi}\right)$$

What should I do next?

Comment: What is "RTS" and why wouldn't you write it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sin{\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)}
&=\frac1{2i}\left(e^{i(\frac\pi2-x)}-e^{-i(\frac\pi2-x)}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(e^{i\frac\pi2-ix}-e^{-i\frac\pi2+ix}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(e^{i\frac\pi2}(e^{-ix})-e^{-i\frac\pi2}(e^{ix})\right)\\
&=\frac1{2i}\left(i(e^{-ix})+i(e^{ix})\right)\\
&=\frac1{2}\left(e^{-ix}+e^{ix}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2}\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)\\
&=\cos{(x)}\\
\end{align}$$
Where I have used Euler's formula to find
$$e^{i\frac\pi2}=\cos{\left(\frac\pi2\right)}+i\sin{\left(\frac\pi2\right)}=i$$
$$e^{-i\frac\pi2}=\cos{\left(-\frac\pi2\right)}+i\sin{\left(-\frac\pi2\right)}=-i$$